# PHP json_encode size limit?

Tags: php, size, limit, json

I'm using a PHP proxy to get the contents of a file. I want to search through that file using the powerfull jQuery options, without having to write all kinds of queries in PHP. Here is my PHP code:

```
$page = file_get_contents( filter_var( $_POST[url], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ) );
die( json_encode( $page ) );
```

If the page loaded gets too big PHP will read the entire document, but json_encoding it will only give the first part of the file, not the entire file. I can't find anything about a size limit on json passed data, but apparently there is one.

the question: is there a workaround to prevent only part of the file being transfered?

I need to grab files from other domains, so reading the contents of a file in jQuery is not really an option.

Comment: The question is not clear. The size of data possible to be converted by `json_encode` is only limited by available memory.

Comment: Can you give us last signs of the JSON that was created and sent to the browser?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just hitting a time limit (default 30 seconds)? Try `set_time_limit(0)`.

Comment: Why do you want to JSON-serialize it anyway if $page is just a string?

Comment: @Frits van Campen: with time limit hit he will not receive anything, not just a part.

Comment: it's not the time limit. Try grabbing http://www.cnn.com this way and pass it back as json encoded data. the data will end like this: "height=\"11\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"><\/a><\/div>\n\t<div id", that's not the complete page. Echoing the data grabbed to the screen does display the correct end: "</script></div>"... so somehow json_encode is loosing the end

Comment: @Mario: dunno... tried as regular data and it worked like a charm. thanks for fixing my problem... one question remains though: is there a size limit for a json_encode? Not that it's a problem for me anymore, but it could be something I run in to another time...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To help others who may be running into problems that they can't explain with json_encode. I've found it helps to know about the json error msg function.

```
json_last_error_msg();
```

I was having a similar problem but it wasn't related to file size. I had malformed utf-8 in the database. You can check your json like this

```
$json = json_encode($data);

if ($json)
    echo $json;
else
    echo json_last_error_msg();
```

PHP docs here [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: Awesome! I'd never figured this out if I didn't come across your answer...

Comment: DUDE, this is great! You saved me bunch of debugging time!

Comment: I was able to fix this issue with json_encode($data, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE)

Comment: @MarkAinsworth your suggestion worked for me too.

Answer (score 13):

PHP 5.3: [ext/json/json.c](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=ext/json/json.c;hb=9c4ef501462cb672df1f6736261a1c8beea77c7e) 
PHP 7 (current): [ext/json/json.c](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=ext/json/json.c)

There is no built-in restriction to the size of JSON serialized data. Not for strings anyway. I would therefore assume you've run into PHPs memory limit or something.

`json_encode`ing a string consistently just adds some escaping and the outer double quotes. Internally that means a bit memory doubling (temporary string concatenation and utf8_to_utf16 conversion/check), so that I ran into my 32MB php memory limit with an 8MB string already. But other than that, there seem to be no arbitrary limits in `json.c`

Comment: the size was way smaller than 8Mb. I 'fixed' it (it's just a workaround) by not importing things as JSON. It's not the PHP memory limit, otherwise I couldn't have 'fixed' the problem by going around JSON

Comment: @patrick it would be worth mentioned how you 'fixed' it and your (workaround) to help others in the future visiting here.

Comment: Like I said above: I fixed it by not encoding

Comment: ... to elaborate on 'not encoding'... I used: exit( $page ) at the end, instead of json_encode( $page )... things didn't need to be encoded in this AJAX application, the initial question still remained though...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar case.
So, I write here.

My website also responded broken jsondata. It is about 8MB.

The cause was the storage has not free.
The result of command of df was displayed "used 100%".

I deleted some files. Then, resolved.

Comment: Worth checking indeed... in my case this was not the problem, I still would like to know where the problem I ran in to came from. It was not a memory issue, there where no errors. Still the problem was there...