# json_encode large PHP array, server fails - 500 error

Tags: php, json

Can't figure out for the life of me why this fails. Large PHP array of objects (1200 rows of data) `var_dump`s just fine. When I `json_encode` the array, the server fails. code: (without actual large json data)

```
function generateId() {
    return substr(uniqid ('', true), -5);
}

$obj=(json_decode(utf8_encode($json), true));


foreach ($obj as $value) {
    $newArray[generateId()] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: Look at the server logs, especially the error log. 500 errors never go unnoticed, they should leave some traces.

Comment: Your foreach firstly needs to be $value not $obj

Comment: What does "fails" mean exactly?

Comment: You might find this enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194393/php-json-encode-size-limit

Comment: Liam answered it... lol... i didn't notice that. Fresh set of eyes always helps, eh?

Comment: Have you tried using `false` for the `json_decode` function?
Nevermind!  Glad he found it.