# json_encode function: special characters

Tags: php, json

Elements of an array containing special characters are converted to empty strings when encoding the array with json_encode:

```
$arr = array ( "funds" => "ComStage STOXX®Europe 600 Techn NR ETF", "time"=>....);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

After JSON encoding the element [funds] is null. It happens only with special characters (copyright, trademark etc) like the ones in "ComStage STOXX®Europe 600 Techn NR ETF".

Any suggestions?

Thanks

UPDATE: This is what solved the problem prior to populating the array (all names are taken from the db):

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Not all special characters are UTF8. The very ASCII "greather than" and "lower than" can create havoc in a json-encoded string. I just had the case today. htmlentities() or htmlenspecialchars(), although doing their job, didn't provide a solution. For now I had to replace them with plus and minus characters, to avoid FF from interpreting them as HTML tag opening and closing characters. Any other solution welcome.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi I found this article helpful: https://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-escape-json-special-characters-using-php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your input has to be encoded as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Because if you try to convert an array of non-utf8 characters you'll be getting 0 as return value.

---

*Since 5.5.0 The return value on failure was changed from null string to FALSE.*

Comment: On php.net is written: `All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.`.

Comment: I've tried cleaning the string to conform to UTF-8 without any success. What worked for me - setting MySQL Names to UTF-8 prior to populating the array: $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
Now all special characters are displayed perfectly fine.

Comment: you might want to use `PDO` instead of `mysqli` btw. imho it offers more functionality :)

Comment: @user2723490 Your suggestion solved the problem for me. Trying to `utf_encode` an accented e was giving me the word "Array" as my result, but getting it on the way out from the database end worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Brothers im facing the issue please check my question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998897/php-json-encode-is-returning-0-zero-value-sometimes

Comment: Please give me such characters which will return 0 on json_encode

Comment: @MuhammadAteek since 5.5.0 it will return false instead

Answer (score 52):

[The manual for json_encode specifies this:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

Thus, try `array_map`ping `utf8_encode()` to your array before you encode it:

```
$arr = array_map('utf8_encode', $arr);
$json = json_encode($arr);

// {"funds":"ComStage STOXX\u00c2\u00aeEurope 600 Techn NR ETF"}
```

For reference, take a look at the differences between [the three examples on this fiddle](https://eval.in/81311). The first doesn't use character encoding, the second uses `htmlentities` and the third uses `utf8_encode` - they all return different results.

For consistency, you should use `utf8_encode()`.

> Docs

- [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode)
- [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map)

Comment: array_map doing nothing

Comment: @MuhammadBabar if you have a question, please ask a new one and we can help you determine why your code isn't working as expected.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Careful! `utf8_encode()` only works if the source is ISO-8859-1! http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 13):

To me, it works this way:

```
# Creating the ARRAY from Result.
$array=array();

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    # Converting each column to UTF8
    $row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    array_push($array,$row);
}

json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use this code:

```
$json = json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $arr))
```

array_map function converts special characters in UTF8 standard

Comment: Your answer appears to be a copy/paste of the code from [the answer from half a year ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20694425/19068), but combined into a single statement.

Comment: Good answer. I salute you sir!

Comment: Careful! `utf8_encode()` only works if the source is ISO-8859-1! http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 5):

Use the below function.

```
function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$item, $key) {
        if (!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid escaping of special characters, I'm passing the flag:

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Like this:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $connection);

Example
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST_GATEWAY,DB_USER_GATEWAY, DB_PASSWORD_GATEWAY);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $connection);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_GATEWAY,$connection);

Answer (score -3):

you should add charset=UTF-8 in meta tag and use json_encode for special characters

`$json = json_encode($arr);`

json_encode function converts special characters in UTF8 standard

Answer (score -4):

### To fix the special character issue you just have to do 2 things

1.`mysql_set_charset('utf8');` // set this line on top of your page in which you are using json.

2. If you are saving json data in database make sure that the particular column collation is set to "`latin1_swedish_ci`".