# What character encoding is this in the JSON file?

Tags: json

I downloaded a 6GB `gz` file from the openlibrary, I extracted it on my ubuntu machine which turned into a 40GB `txt` file. When inspecting the head of the file using `head`, I find this string:

```
"name": "Mawlu\u0304d Qa\u0304sim Na\u0304yit Bulqa\u0304sim"
```

What encoding is this? Is it possible to get something that is human readable or does it look like it will require the data source to be exported correctly again?

Comment: Looks like ASCII, though it could be anything. The `\u...` things are part of the JSON specification and should be handled by your JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

It's standard escaping of unicode characters in a javascript literal string.

the string is `Mawlūd Qāsim Nāyit Bulqāsim`

Answer (score 1):

This is plain JSON encoding. Your JSON parser will translate the `\uNNNN` references to Unicode characters. See also: [json_encode function: special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694317/json-encode-function-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

looks like unicode

http://www.charbase.com/0304-unicode-combining-macron

U+0304: COMBINING MACRON