# json_encode() returns null for special characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, turkish

I know that there are lot of questions on this. I have tried many things but I couldn't fix it. Perhaps I failed executing the solutions because of my limited knowledge?

I select data from mysql database and use json_encode() function on it. This works , except for the data which contains special characters(Turkish). For those values , json returns null. How can I fix this?

Here is my simple php code:

```
<?php

require('init.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename;";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


array_push($response,array("X"=>$row["x"],"Y"=>$row["y"]));

}

echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

in mysql , columns are set to utf8-turkish. I have tried things like setting headers , calling some functions , recreating php files in utf8 encoding etc.. but none did work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode function: special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694317/json-encode-function-special-characters)

Comment: Have you set the mysqli charset http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Hello Riggs . no I didn't try that yet. Do I need to write that in my connection script(init.php)?

Comment: Riggs I did use it now. For a special character , instead of getting null , I get this : "\u00d6" . Does this mean it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Using mysqli_set_charset function in my connection script solved the problem. Couldn't find this on similar questions. Thanks to user "RiggsFolly" .

Answer (score -3):

Add `TRUE`:  `json_decode($string, TRUE);`  That will get you utf8 characters instead of Unicode escape sequences (like `\u00d6`).

You need `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`) in the connection, in the table, and in the html.  See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831).