# Is there a max length for JSON field?

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

Hello and good evening,

I writing a simple PHP ecommerce website and I've stumbled upon a problem while doing the administration portion of it.
I'm currently trying to do an AJAX request to fill some fields on a bootstrap modal and for that I go get the data from a database:

```
function editProductResponse($productId)
{
    require 'app/database/Database.php';
    require 'app/models/Product.php';
    require 'app/models/ProductImage.php';

    $product = new Product();
    $object = $product->getProduct($productId);
    $data = $object[0];
    $array = [
        "id" => $data->id,
        "name" => $data->name,
        //"description" => $data->description,
        "price" => $data->price,
        "stock" => $data->stock,
        "sold" => $data->sold,
        "added" => $data->added,
        "type" => $data->type,
        "subtype" => $data->subtype,
        "discount" => $data->discount
    ];
    echo print_r($data);
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

That's my `ajax.php` function that gets that actual data and this works fine (bear in mind the commented part of the array is not a mistake, I'll explain that bellow; also i'm doing an array for debug purposes):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => MSI Nightblade MI2-027XES Gaming
    [description] => Forjado com a paix�o pelo jogo, o MSI Nightblade MI2 foi feito para aqueles que anseiam por uma experi�ncia de jogo imersiva. Com armazenamento em abund�ncia, refrigera��o eficiente e gr�ficos de alta qualidade, esta pequena m�quina gaming est� pronta para desbloquear a sua pr�xima aventura gaming.
    [price] => 799
    [stock] => 147
    [sold] => 32
    [added] => 2010-11-22
    [type] => COMPUTER
    [subtype] => DESKTOP
    [discount] => 10
)
1{"id":1,"name":"MSI Nightblade MI2-027XES Gaming","price":799,"stock":147,"sold":32,"added":"2010-11-22","type":"COMPUTER","subtype":"DESKTOP","0":"discount => 10"}
```

This is my response in the browser log. Everything appears to be working fine and it is.
So my **problem** is when I actually uncomment the description part from the array. If I do so, I get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => MSI Nightblade MI2-027XES Gaming
    [description] => Forjado com a paix�o pelo jogo, o MSI Nightblade MI2 foi feito para aqueles que anseiam por uma experi�ncia de jogo imersiva. Com armazenamento em abund�ncia, refrigera��o eficiente e gr�ficos de alta qualidade, esta pequena m�quina gaming est� pronta para desbloquear a sua pr�xima aventura gaming.
    [price] => 799
    [stock] => 147
    [sold] => 32
    [added] => 2010-11-22
    [type] => COMPUTER
    [subtype] => DESKTOP
    [discount] => 10
)
1
```

I left the `echo print_r` to avoid any confusion on both results.

After I got this response it made me wonder if there's any sort of limit to JSON or if there's some sort of problem with the `TEXT` SQL data type as the `description` field is of this type.

As requested, this is the debug response of the actual array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => MSI Nightblade MI2-027XES Gaming
    [description] => Forjado com a paix�o pelo jogo, o MSI Nightblade MI2 foi feito para aqueles que anseiam por uma experi�ncia de jogo imersiva. Com armazenamento em abund�ncia, refrigera��o eficiente e gr�ficos de alta qualidade, esta pequena m�quina gaming est� pronta para desbloquear a sua pr�xima aventura gaming.
    [price] => 799
    [stock] => 147
    [sold] => 32
    [added] => 2010-11-22
    [type] => COMPUTER
    [subtype] => DESKTOP
    [discount] => 10
)
1
```

Comment: so... what's the problem? the invalid characters? No, there's no... limit to how big a json string can be. at least, no limit that's any different to the max length a string can be.

Comment: the problem is exactly that, if I add the description there's an empty response.. what I can't figure out is why

Comment: print the array

Comment: yeah I saw that just now, already corrected it, I'm editing the question. thank you @KevinB

Comment: @KevinB as you requested I included the response when I print the array

Comment: I don't see anything that would be causing what you are seeing, but it certainly isn't due to the length. It may be due to the value of the description, but i kinda doubt that too (and you can easily rule that out)

Comment: hmm... encoding problem maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694317/json-encode-function-special-characters

Comment: That's what I was just thinking. To be sure, though, see what the error is with your JSON when you try to encode it: `var_dump(json_last_error());` This should output `5`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the issue. There was a problem with some of my encoding in the database as I had some portuguese special characters that weren't correctly converted.