# Cannot output a big string block without break lines (nginx+php)

Tags: php, json, nginx

I try to print a big JSON block (100k) to the browser, but the server fails without an error.

For example:

`echo 'var config = ' . json_encode( $config ) . ';' . PHP_EOL;`

I Have found that if i send a small piece, it's OK.
I have found that if I put line breaks in the JSON string, it's OK even if the string is 400k.

For example:

`$config_json = json_encode( $config );
$config_json = str_replace( '},', '},' . PHP_EOL, $config_json );
echo 'var config = ' . $config_json . ';' . PHP_EOL;`

But the breaklines breaks my JSON.

So, if it's a buffer setting, why the `PHP_EOL` helps?

I have tried also to split the JSON to pieces like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156563/1009525, But without success, Only the breaklines helps me.

Comment: is your json valid? have you validated using a online validator tool perhaps?

Comment: Yes. But it's not a JSON problem, it's fails for each large string.

Comment: Have you tried disabling buffering? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering ? If that works, you can do it just for this one response: "Buffering can also be enabled or disabled by passing “yes” or “no” in the “X-Accel-Buffering” response header field."

Comment: Is the string displayed in a <pre> html tag ? If yes, i know there can be some errors when printing large strings

Comment: Any error you get when you try to print the json like **503 server capacity problem** or anything like that. If nothing is showing then enable `ini_set('error_reporting', 32767);` and check again

Comment: What error do you see? Is there anything in the nginx error log?

Comment: Check this link maybe helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Comment: have you tried looping through your `$config` variable and building json string like this `$str = '{'; $str .= '{ id:'. $value['id'].'}'; ...  $str .= '}';`

Answer (score 1):

As you write

> the server fails without an error

I presume you mean that the server sends a response to the client (status code: 200 - no error), but the response body (the content) is empty (this is the failure).

You should check this because if actually the server sends a response **with content** then the issue is not with php, nginx or buffering.

Otherwise (as suggested in comments) maybe the JSON instead of inside a `<script>` - `</script>` block may be wrapped between `<pre>` tags and this could be the problem (but I can't help unless you post more of your code).

---

From now on I assume the response sent from the server is **empty**

The code you posted is valid and is supposed to handle correctly the output string you're building up (that's far below PHP limits).

Said that it seems a weird buffering issue. I write "weird" because as far as I know (and I took time to do some research too) buffering should not be influenced by line breaks.

---

> I have found that if I put line breaks in the JSON string, it's OK even if the string is 400k.

A quick workaround to solve your problem is to output a **valid** JSON **with** line breaks. You just need to specify an option to `json_encode`:

```
echo 'var config = ' . json_encode( $config, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
```

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` tells `json_encode` to format the json to be more readable and doing so will add line breaks.

(Note that this option is available for PHP 5.4.0 and above)

---

I hope the above solution works for you.

Anyway I strongly suggest you to investigate further the issue in order to let the original code too to work.

First you should ensure you're running a recent and stable version of both **nginx** and **php**.

Then I would check nginx configuration file, php-fpm configuration (if you're using php-fpm) and finally php configuration.

Also check php, nginx, and php-fpm error logs.

Comment: JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is available on PHP versions > 5.4.0, please add a small comment on your answer on that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

try using php heredoc for echoing http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have `PHP` version > 5.4.0 installed on your server a quick workaround could be something like this. The below snippet works for a test array. Initial test was with an array of 250Kb. Since i can't post the actual test array here is a [test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/839094e89439dccaf3f5156b8538b40f16e358cd) link with a smaller example. It is as the result of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` though.

```
$out = json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$out = str_replace( ':{', ':' . PHP_EOL . '    ' . '{', $out );
$out = str_replace( '},', PHP_EOL . '    },', $out );
$out = str_replace( ',', ',' . PHP_EOL  . '     ', $out );
$out = str_replace( '},' . PHP_EOL . '     ', '},' . PHP_EOL . ' ', $out );
$out = str_replace( '}}', PHP_EOL . '    }' . PHP_EOL . '}', $out );

echo $out;
```