# var_dump(json_encode($data)) returns bool(false)

Tags: php, json

After getting result from Sql query, I stored my result in a *$data* array, which after **var_dump($data)** looks somewhat like this:

```
array(100) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["qid"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["q_no_on_paper"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["question_text"]=>
    string(139) "&nbsp; Consider the following          statements-                         &nbsp;                          1- The Centre recently unveiled the expanded version of the. . ."
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
    ["qid"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["q_no_on_paper"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["question_text"]=>
    string(138) ". There is dispute over the Tipaimukh hydraulic project between India          and                         A. Bhutan                       B. Nepal                        C.. . ."
  }  ...
```

The array is long, so this is just a part of it.
Now when I do `json_encode($data);` , and then *var_dump* it, I get `bool(false)`.
I tried to use `json_last_error()` after following the Example #1 in this [PHP documentation link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) , it shows `- No errors`

Where am I going wrong? Why is it not encoding it?

**EDIT:**
The `["question_text"]` contains some *html* text.

Comment: You might potentially be running into a memory limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194393/php-json-encode-size-limit

Comment: PHP error log tell you anything?

Comment: Do yuo have error reporting on?

Comment: Did you try a simple `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: @JeremyHarris I tried with a small list, still the problem is persisting. I dont think there is a memory problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried simple echo `json_encode($data);` It shows nothing.Blank.

Comment: I see some white space characters in var_dump($data) result. This makes JSON invalid and hence json_encode returns bool. Check the following index in your array...
["question_text"]=>
    string(139) "&nbsp; Consider the following          statements-

Comment: You will have to show us some real code if you want any more help, it looks like we have all run out of guesses

Comment: @Rahi your statement made me dig deeper into this thing. So I got a blog about adding [HTML](https://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) and I figured out where is the problem. Actually in my 3rd object, the ["question_text"] contains html quotations in this form: `" "` .So i just need to replace it with *&quot* and I think it will work fine.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Can you please accept my answer posted below?

Answer (score 1):

**This may help you out**,

Although this is not documented on the version log , `non-UTF8` handling behavior has changed in `5.5`, in a way that can make debugging difficult.

Passing a non `UTF-8` string to `json_encode()` will make the function `return false` in **PHP 5.5**, while it will only nullify this string (and only this one) in previous versions.

In a `Latin-1 encoded file`, write this:

```
<?php
$a = array('é', 1);
var_dump(json_encode($a));
?>

PHP < 5.4:
string(8) "[null,1]"

PHP >= 5.5:
bool(false)
```

`PHP 5.5` has it right of course (if encoding fails, return false) but its likely to introduce errors when updating to 5.5 because previously you could get the rest of the `JSON` even when one string was not in `UTF8` (if this string wasn't used, you'd never notify it's nulled)

So you may encountered the later example of **PHP >= 5.5**

See at **php.net** documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#115733

Answer (score -1):

I see some white space/HTML characters (like \n, \t, \r) in var_dump($data) result. This makes JSON invalid and hence json_encode returns false. Check the following index in your array...

```
["question_text"]=> string(139) "&nbsp; Consider the          following statements-
```

Comment: It's a string. Doesn't matter if there's white space in it or not.

Comment: White space characters like \n and \t etc are known to cause issues in JSON encoding. Why vote down when the question poster also mentioned it did solve his issue?

Comment: Known by whom? Have you actually tried this? It would be a pretty poor standard if it couldn't handle whitespace characters in a string. The question poster has no idea what they're talking about, and seems convinced that JSON can't handle a simple double quote, an equally dubious suggestion.

Comment: As per http://json.org/ 
any Unicode character except " or \ or control-character

    \"

    \
    /
    \b
    \f
    \n
    \r
    \t
    \u four-hex-digits

Comment: You're confusing JSON data with the string used to create it.

Comment: @miken32 can json_encode be used to encode string containing `"` in it? I think it breaks the encoding.

Comment: It would be a pretty poor standard if it couldn't handle " characters in a string.